# Fun things to do with generators and sequences

Tags: c#, linq, iterator, generator

Does anyone else feel that the iterators are coming up short when you want to take a part a sequence piece by piece?

Maybe I should just start writing my code in F# (btw anybody knows if F# uses lazy evaluation) but I've found myself wanting a way to pull at a sequence in a very distinct way.

e.g.

```
// string.Split implemented as a generator, with lazy evaluation
var it = "a,b,c".GetSplit(',').GetEnumerator();
it.MoveNext();
var a = it.Current;
it.MoveNext();
it.MoveNext();
var c = it.Current;
```

That works, but I don't like it, it is ugly. So can I do this?

```
var it = "a,b,c".GetSplit(',');
string a;
var c = it.Yield(out a).Skip(1).First();
```

That's better. But I'm wondering if there's another way of generalizing the same semantic, maybe this is good enough. Usually I'm doing some embedded string parsing, that's when this pops out.

There's also the case where I wish to consume a sequence up to a specific point, then basically, fork it (or clone it, that's better). Like so

```
var s = "abc";
IEnumerable<string> a;
var b = s.Skip(1).Fork(out a);
var s2 = new string(a.ToArray()); // "bc"
var s3 = new string(b.ToArray()); // "bc"
```

This last one, might not be that useful at first, I find that it solves backtracking issues rather conveniently.

My question is do we need this? or does it already exist in some manner and I've just missed it?

Comment: "anybody knows if F# uses lazy evaluation" - not by default. F# sequences are lazy like in C# (they're `IEnumerable` too). F# has lambda functions (again, like C#) and some syntactic sugar for lazily evaluated values (which compiles to a function underneath).

Comment: With what purpose in mind? Having syntax / methods etc is *fine* - but unless you know of a valid sensible use-case... why bother? Re the fork - "Push LINQ" (MiscUtil) may be of interest there.

Comment: Intellectual stimuli? Amuse me... sometimes I just like doing research. Gotta checkout Push LINQ.

Comment: What on earth is the use case of that push LINQ stuff you did with Jon, Marc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sequences basically work OK at what they do, which is to provide a simple interface that yields a stream of values on demand. If you have more complicated demands then you're welcome to use a more powerful interface.

For instance, your string examples look like they could benefit being written as a parser: that is, a function that consumes a sequence of characters from a stream and uses internal state to keep track of where it is in the stream.

Comment: You know, what I really would want. I would want something like Boost Spirit, it meta programming and operator overloading to basically create a C++ DSL which can be used to consume string input. It's freakishly compiler intensive and slows down the compilation of your program a lot, but it works and it's kind of cool to have something that powerful built on top of the C++ language. Fundamentally speaking, it's still consuming character streams but at that level it's really awkward to describe some high level function. Which is kind of what I'm trying to do here.

Comment: I've never seen a parser framework for C# that I've liked. You mentioned F#; there you have `fslex`/`fsyacc` (part of the PowerPack) or the `FParsec` library.

Comment: Really? You know, function programming language always had that in favor. Maybe I should roll some parsers in F# but consume them through C#... that makes sense.

Comment: Btw, have you tried Coco/R for C#? it's sort of nice. It's a compiler generator for C# maybe you differentiate between the two. It's fundamentally different from Spirit but in the end it does the same thing.